# turtlebot urdf.xacro file for VLP-16 3D sensor

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to add new sensor Velodyne VLP16  for the turtlebot as given in http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials/indigo/Adding%20New%203D%20Sensor.

How to generate a urdf xacro file or where to find ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257237/turtlebot-urdf.xacro-file-for-vlp-16-3d-sensor/) by [moksgo](https://answers.ros.org/users/29610/moksgo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2017-03-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can find the URDF description of VLP16 in the package [velodyne_description](http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne_description).

Here is the direct link to the VLP-16.urdf.xacro file: https://bitbucket.org/DataspeedInc/velodyne_simulator/raw/b2b4496e8150c4e4082a0b8227922a721f4dc91d/velodyne_description/urdf/VLP-16.urdf.xacro

Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2017-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [moksgo](https://answers.ros.org/users/29610/moksgo/) on 2017-03-21**:
Thank You.